# Bootstrap3 navbar collapse list appears to the bottom of other elements in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to do a single webpage. I have a problem that Bootstrap3 navbar collapse list appears under other elements.

I tried to set the list position to relative and also the following elements position.

Also changed opacity and put background but it didn't work.
I have an assignment and the navbar shouldn't be fixed to the top.
It should be like in the following pic, not to cover other elements:

[image]

[here's the page](https://reem-almasri.github.io/repository2/index.html)

[and the code repository](https://github.com/Reem-Almasri/repository2)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Bradley Hand, cursive;
  font-size: 24px; 
}

p {margin:0}
/*  Header */
#header-nav {
  background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  border-radius: 0;
  border:#000000 solid 3px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.navbar-brand h1 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #515151;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-brand a:hover, .navbar-brand a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #acacac;
}
#nav-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav-list a {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px #000;
  font: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar-collapse > #nav-list > li > a:hover {
  background: #acacac;
}
.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle, .navbar-header .icon-bar {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -53px;
}
.nav>li>a {
  display:none;
}
/* end Header */

#Menu{
  font-size:3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#000000;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div > .row{
margin: 15px;
color: #000000;
}
.itm, .cntnt{
  background-color: #acacac;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.itm{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.cntnt {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
/* Medium devices */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {


}

/* Small devices */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 

}

/* Extra small devices */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Header */
  .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .navbar-brand h1 { 
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 100vh;
  }

 div > .navbar-collapse{
  border: hidden;
  max-height: 175px;  
 }

  #navbar-collapse > #nav-list > li{
    border: #000 solid 2px;
  }
  #navbar-collapse > #nav-list > li > a {
    color: #000;
    display:block;
    font-size: 4vw;
  }

  /* End Header */
  #Menu{
    font-size:5vw;
  }
  div > .row{
    margin: 2%;
  }
  .itm{
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  .cntnt {
    font-size: 2vw;
  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h1>Food, LLC</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
        
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse opacity-100">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#Chicken">Chicken</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Beef">Beef</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Sushi">Sushi</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="Menu" class="container-fluid text-center">Our Menu</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <p class="itm" id="Chicken">Chicken</p>
      <p class="cntnt">
      
      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Does the demo above show the problem? Please revise as needed, and take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: You haven't tagged Bootstrap 3 per the instructions on the twitter-bootstrap tag. If I do it it affects the reputation credit I earn for helping. Please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is this:

```
#header-nav {
    height: 100px;
}
```

It restricts the navbar's ability to expand as needed.

When in doubt, strip out your custom stuff. 99% of the time that's where the problem lies when using a library.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Bradley Hand, cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: rgb(125, 125, 125);
  border-radius: 0;
  border: #000000 solid 3px;
  /* height: 100px; ----------------------------- NO! */
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #515151;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover,
.navbar-brand a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #acacac;
}

#nav-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav-list a {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px #000;
  font: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar-collapse>#nav-list>li>a:hover {
  background: #acacac;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle,
.navbar-header .icon-bar {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -53px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: none;
}


/* end Header */

#Menu {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div>.row {
  margin: 15px;
  color: #000000;
}

.itm,
.cntnt {
  background-color: #acacac;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.itm {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.cntnt {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/* Medium devices */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}


/* Small devices */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}


/* Extra small devices */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Header */
  .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .navbar-brand h1 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  div>.navbar-collapse {
    border: hidden;
    max-height: 175px;
  }
  #navbar-collapse>#nav-list>li {
    border: #000 solid 2px;
  }
  #navbar-collapse>#nav-list>li>a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
  /* End Header */
  #Menu {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  div>.row {
    margin: 2%;
  }
  .itm {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  .cntnt {
    font-size: 2vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h1>Food, LLC</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse opacity-100">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#Chicken">Chicken</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Beef">Beef</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Sushi">Sushi</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="Menu" class="container-fluid text-center">Our Menu</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <p class="itm" id="Chicken">Chicken</p>
      <p class="cntnt">


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this solved the problem with the placement, any tips for hover please?

Comment: You've asked two questions in one post. Please don't do that, and don't ask questions in comments, especially on resolved posts. Also, hover seems fine in the demo above.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this style values to the respective class

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    z-index: 999999;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you! that solved one of the problems (no longer going behind the body), but unfortunatly still have it going on top of other elements, and hover is still not working.

Comment: Custom CSS like this shouldn't be necessary for a fairly standard Bootstrap navbar.